# keycloak redirect_uri is not forming correctly when called from Spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

we are using nginx(as proxy SSL enabled), Spring boot1.2.2 and keycloak 
    1.9.8.
    we are deploying spring boot application as a jar and done necessary setup 
    for keycloak in application.properties. Without SSL everything works fine 
    but whenever we used SSL, spring boot application is not forwarding 
    proto(https) and port(8443) to keycloak so we always get invalid 
    redirect_uri exception.

```
I tried setting follwing configuration in application.properties
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-port

Please suggest what needs to be done.

Thanks & Regards,
Chandrashekhar
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue is resolved. we have set proto and port pragmatically in embedded tomcat container through spring Initializer class.

```
    @Override
    public void customize(final ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                //final TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
                tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> { 
                    connector.setScheme("https");
                    connector.setProxyPort(443);                        
                    //connector.setScheme("https");
                    //connector.setProxyPort(8443);
                    //connector.setScheme("http");
                    //connector.setProxyPort(8080);                        
                });
                LOGGER.info("Enabled secure scheme (https).");
        } else {
            LOGGER.warn("Could not change protocol scheme because Tomcat is not used as servlet container.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the spring Initializer class? which class are you overriding? please provide more code